# How do i implement positive numbers in agda

Tags: agda

So im trying to define the set of positive natural numbers  {1, 2, 3, . . .} in
Agda.

```
data Nat : Set where
 one : Nat
 succ : Nat -> Nat
{-#BUILTIN NATURAL Nat #-}
```

this is how i did it, but it still takes 0 with it.

how do u make it start from 1 ?

Answer (score 4):

Agda allows to overload number literals via the `FROMNAT` built-in:

```
open import Agda.Builtin.Nat
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Unit.Base

Positive : Nat -> Set
Positive zero = ⊥
Positive _    = ⊤

data Nat₁ : Set where
 one  : Nat₁
 succ : Nat₁ -> Nat₁

toNat₁ : ∀ n {_ : Positive n} -> Nat₁
toNat₁  0 {()}
toNat₁  1            = one
toNat₁ (suc (suc n)) = succ (toNat₁ (suc n))

{-# BUILTIN FROMNAT toNat₁ #-}

fail : Nat₁
fail = 0

ok : Nat₁
ok = 1
```

Here `Positive n` is a constraint which is unsatisfiable when `n` is `0` and trivially satisfiable when `n` is positive. So in `fail` the constraint computes to `⊥` and you get an unsolved meta of this type, which is impossible to solve (assuming the type system is consistent), because this type is uninhabited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Is there any BUILTIN for posNat?

Comment: @Abdiabdisson, [no](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/built-ins.html). That's too specific, I think. Why would you need them? That `FROMNAT` stuff seems to work.

Comment: No not really, just thinking if we could make it a bit more easier. :)